# How to remove permissions from Expo managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

Today i built my app for Android and after that i upload it to google play. Everything worked great since i got so many permissions that i dont really need.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fWE4.png)

They are 13

> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
> android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET,
> android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
> android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
> android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
> android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, android.permission.VIBRATE,
> android.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
> com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE,
> com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE

I need only for write and read storage for ***async storage lib***
So i read some information about how to remove it. And i tried follwoing steps
First i add in app.js following line

```
"android": {

      "permissions": [

        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",

        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",

        "READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"

      ],
```

Not worked then
delete **expo-location from package-lock.json** and **node_modules folder** and ran **npm install** - again not worked.
I used eas build with SDK version 41.0.0 and npm version 7.15.1

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official documentation says:

> To use ONLY the following minimum necessary permissions and none of
> the extras supported by Expo in a default managed app, set permissions
> to []. The minimum necessary permissions do not require a Privacy
> Policy when uploading to Google Play Store and are: • receive data
> from Internet • view network connections • full network access •
> change your audio settings • prevent device from sleeping   To use ALL
> permissions supported by Expo by default, do not specify the
> permissions key.    To use the minimum necessary permissions ALONG
> with certain additional permissions, specify those extras in
> permissions, e.g.  [ "CAMERA", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" ].

Thats why you have extra permissions, you can read about it [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions)

Comment: What if I wanted to remove everything? Is it somehow possible, without manually removing them from the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely but I found the solution. Just ran

> npm uninstall react-native-maps

.Maybe this lib cause that problem